# PHP-Having issues echoing from mysql using GET

Tags: php, mysql, database, get

I am new at PHP, and I am trying to echo a particular field from my DB using the ID in my URL as reference. However instead of echoing the value it echo's back the ID.

What am doing wrong? Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks in advance.

I an trying to echo the datecreated field from ID that I have in my URL.
The url is www.example.com/client_profile.php?id=1001

```
<div class="thumb-info mb-md">
    <img src="assets/images/!logged-user.jpg" class="rounded img-responsive" alt="John Doe">
    <div class="thumb-info-title">
        <?php
            echo $_GET['id'];  //Output: myquery
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM client WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<span class='thumb-info-inner'>$row.['datecreated'].</span>";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Updated Code***

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "my user", "my pass") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("my db");

$id = (int)$_GET['id'];  //Output: myquery
echo $id;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM client WHERE id = $id");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<span class='thumb-info-inner'>" . $row['datecreated'] . "</span>";
}?>
```

Which echo's both ID and the Value from DB

Comment: are you saying on this line `echo "<span class='thumb-info-inner'>$row.['datecreated'].</span>";}?>` it's outputting 1001?

Comment: @Leeish yes the id beeing 1001

Comment: `1001` is coming from `echo $id;`. There's no way that's coming from `$row['datecreated']`

Comment: Can you have more than one row with `id = 1001`? If there's only one row, why do you need a `while` loop?

Comment: @Barmar your absolutely right that's where it came from thanks your very much for the help.

Comment: Ah I see I missed the issue with the `1001` output. I thought that echo had some other purpose which is why I left it in. So the issue is now resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div class="thumb-info mb-md"> <img src="assets/images/!logged-user.jpg" class="rounded img-responsive" alt="John Doe">
    <div class="thumb-info-title">
        <?php
            $id = (int)$_GET['id'];  //Output: myquery
          echo $id;
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM client WHERE id = $id");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<span class='thumb-info-inner'>" . $row['datecreated'] . "</span>";
          }?>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your current code your concatenation was off for displaying the `$row` data. You also were open to SQL injections. To fix the SQL injections I cast your `id` as an int, here's a thread on that [SQL Injection Protection - Cast from string to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394467/sql-injection-protection-cast-from-string-to-int). You also could use the `mysql_real_string_escape` (order of words might be off there).
You should switch over to PDO and parameterized queries when you can though, [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Thanks. So I copie/pasted your code and I still get the same result.

Comment: Am I suppose to connect to database first?

Comment: You are getting `Reference ##` as output currently right? Yes, you should be connect to the db. See the manual for a sample, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php.

Comment: Ok, success but no success right now it echo's the ID and the proper value inside the DB.

Here's the code that I am using see the updated code in the post

Comment: I don't know what you mean by Reference ##

Comment: What's the current issue? Wasn't the issue the data wasn't coming from the DB? The reference message I was referring to is when you are calling an object incorrectly but that doesn't appear to be this issue. It also is heard to search for "reference" so I can't find the exact error I thought you were seeing.